# Remove leading zeros in an int array

Tags: java, arrays, int

Attempt to merge numbers by removing the leading zeros in the Int array.

```
int[] array = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 5 };
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    String.format("%09d", array[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(array[i]);
}
```

Desired output:

```
405
```

Comment: Is your **Output** the desired one or the one you currently get and don't want? By the way, this is not a working example...

Comment: Your first loop does nothing (useful).

Comment: Do you mean remove the zeros from the array, or print the array without the leading zeros?  Very different questions with different solutions!

Answer (score 6):

Since an array has a fixed size you cannot remove any element from an array.  Thus I assume you want to have a new array without the leading zeros.

With Java 9+ ([`dropWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)) was not present in Java 8) you can do it this way:

```
int[] array = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 5 };
int[] withoutLeadingZeros = Arrays.stream(array).dropWhile(i -> i == 0).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(withoutLeadingZeros)); // [4, 0, 5]
```

EDIT
In case the result is intended to be a `String`:

```
String withoutLeadingZeros = Arrays.stream(array).dropWhile(i -> i == 0).collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, (l, r) -> l.append(r)).toString();
System.out.println(withoutLeadingZeros); // 405
```

EDIT
In case the result is intended to be an `int`:

```
int number = Arrays.stream(array).reduce((l, r) -> l * 10 + r).getAsInt();
System.out.println(number); // 405
```

Comment: I've updated my answer  showing how to get a `String` or an `int` result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by inserting a boolean.

```
  boolean leadingZeroFinished=false;
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       if(array[i]!=0) {
           leadingZeroFinished=true;
       }
       if(leadingZeroFinished) {
          System.out.println(array[i])
       }
  }
```

If you also want to remove the element, you better use a List

Answer (score 1):

```
    int[] array = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 5 };

    int i = 0;
    for (; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > 0)
            break;
    }

    for (; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Does this work (compile)? Is `i` known in the second loop? I haven't ran it but it looks like it will just print the array as is?

Comment: this will not compile, check it first.

Comment: Yes it works, it's not necessarily to write the initialization inside for block, you can write it as following:
i=0;
for (;;){
if (i<size) break;
...
...
...
i++;
}

Answer (score 0):

try this,if you want to print:

```
int[] arr = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 5 };
boolean isNotLeadingZero=false;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if((arr[i] != 0)  || isNotLeadingZero){
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
        isNotLeadingZero= true;
    }
}
```

**output**

```
405
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
boolean foundNonZero = false;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    foundNonZero |= (arr[i] != 0);
    if(foundNonZero) {
       System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int[] arr = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 5 };

        int i,j;

        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i]!=0)
                break;
        }

        j=0;

        for(;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            arr[j]=arr[i];
            j++;
        }



        for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

i have shifted the elements as you asked to remove the leading zeroes

Answer (score 0):

Convert your array into a number then print it:

```
    int[] array = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 5 };
    int exp = 1;
    long total =0;
    for (int i = array.length -1; i >=0; i-- ) {
        total += array[i]*exp;
        exp *=10;
    }


    System.out.println(total);
```

Then you can even use the result for further computations.